# special characters in SPARQL variables

Tags: sparql

I'm trying to make a SPARQL query, that returns a variable which contains two words, separated by something.. actually, I try to get a variable like ?πληθυσμός_population (greek and english). however, I'd prefer something different than "_", for example an "/" or "-" or even a ":" so that I can do something like "?Ελλ:Πληθυσμός/Eng:Population". How can I do this in a SPARQL query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [grammar for SPARQL variable names](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#rVARNAME) does not allow  chars like /, :, or -, because these (and several others) have reserved meanings in SPARQL.

However, you have plenty of other choices. For example, a middle dot '·' is allowed, as is any combination character from the [Unicode combining diacritical range](http://orwell.ru/test/Unicode/_?6), or indeed any Unicode char in the ranges mentioned in the `PN_CHAR_BASE` grammar rule. Knock yourself out trying to find a char you fancy :)

I would point out, by the way, that using an underscore is actually a pretty well-established practice for separating two words in variables names.

Comment: actually I am using underscore but I wanted something more suitable, since I'm separating word belonging to different languages.I'll try the links you posted.thnx